# Storing data, originally in a dictionary sequence to a dataframe in the json format of a webpage

Tags: json, pandas, dictionary

I'm new to pandas. How to store data, originally in a dictionary sequence to a DataFrame in the json format of a webpage?

Comment: Hard to know what are you looking for, do you mind posting the dataframe and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpreting the question keeping in mind that you have the url of the webpage you want to read. Inspect that url and check if the data needed, is available in the json format. If present, an url will be provided containing all the data. We need that url in the following code:
First, import the pandas module.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests 
import json
URL="url of the webpage having the json file"
r=requests.get(URL)
data= r.json()
```

Create the dataframe df.

```
df=pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
```

Print the dataframe to check whether you have received the required one.

```
print(df)
```

I hope this answers your question.